# React i18n, check if translation exists?

Tags: internationalization, react-i18next

Is there a way to check if a locale exists on react app ?
Like a boolean true/false

Answer (score 27):

Yes, you can check if your language variable exists with `i18n.exists()` method:

You can extract `i18n` from `useTranslation` hook.

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
```

Then call `i18n.exists('my.key')`, for example:

```
i18n.exists("common.values.active")
```

https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#exists

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [onLoaded](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#onloaded)

```
i18next.on('loaded', function(loaded) {})
```

Gets fired on loaded resources.

And [onFailedLoading](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#onfailedloading)

```
i18next.on('failedLoading', function(lng, ns, msg) {})
```

Gets fired if loading resources failed (after the in-built retry algorithm).

In case of react app you could use [useTranslation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense) hook to get *ready* boolean

```
// additional ready will state if translations are loaded or not
```

`const { t, i18n, ready } = useTranslation('ns1', { useSuspense: false });`

Personally, I am using *ready* in my root file could be *index.js* or *App.js* or whatever you have, and I am checking if translations is ready then I show my App